# Oracle error in Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, oracle, scheduled-tasks

We have a C# program which is scheduled to run in Task Scheduler on Windows Server 2003, designed to delete out-of-date files in a folder based on information drawn from multiple Oracle databases.  I can execute the application manually and everything works fine - logged in either as myself with administrative rights, or logged in as the assigned task user which has Users rights.

When the task user is logged off the machine, though, the application fails on each database with one of two errors: either

> ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA

or

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.

All of these databases are using a connect string (retrieved from another, SQL Server, database) which, as I stated before, connect and run just fine when operated manually.  I have been all over the web looking for tips which might apply to this circumstance and have not come up with a definitive answer.

Is there anyone reading this message who might know the answer to this problem?  Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: What method are you using to connect to the Oracle DBs ? OLE DB ? ADO.NET ? ODBC ?

Comment: Task Scheduler provides a runtime environment which is not a "full desktop" and OLE DB needs such an environment esp. regarding permissions... to make it work use ADO.NET which works just fine in that case...

Answer (score 4):

What user is your scheduled task set to execute as?  One of the same users you tested as, or another account?

Regardless, it doesn't sound like a permissions issue, as much as the [`ORACLE_HOME`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORACLE_HOME) environment variable not being set.  (It looks like your program is probably trying to connect through a [`tnsnames.ora`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora) file that can't be found.)  You may need to have the scheduled task first launch a batch file that sets the environment, then continues to call your C# program.

Comment: If you are running this manually .. it makes me wonder if a batchfile process if it's running from a batch process may have the command line params messed up , or the environment variables are not being set or stored properly via the execution of the batchfile process. running manually you would think would yield the same results.. check out all the file dependencies related to that Scheduled Task.. what if it's pointing to the wrong DB or Server in the stored batchfile..?? Perhaps it's a Connection String that's pointing to a test server or one that's non existing ...just Q&A

Comment: That was my first impression too, but there is no TNSNAMES.ORA file in the mix - it's all done through connect strings.  Here's an example: DRIVER={Oracle in Orahome};DBQ=VPDEV1.WORLD;UID=web_app;PWD=web_app;

Comment: @MikePreston That connect strings needs either a TNSNAMES.ORA or an ONAMES-Server to work - otherwise it can't resolve `VPDEV1.WORLD` !

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues, but with some java app. The same happened - manual task execution was fine, but automated execution always failed (same account!).

Check with your admin (or maybe you can do it yourself) and set your C# app to be executed by the admin account (testing only!) or see whether there are any other scheduled tasks and interrogate them to see which windows account they use and how it's set up. I remember that we (I + admin) had to experiment a bit, but finally he created a new privileged account (a copy of some other existing one) to execute the scheduled task.